# Test Factory to call another Test Factory

Tags: testng

Need a direction. I have searched everywhere but could not get an answer whether a test factory can call another test factory.

Example : the first test factory gets me the test suites and for each suite, another test factory is called that will get the test cases for that suite.

Here's a sample code:

```
public class clsTestSuites{ 
    @Factory(dataProvider="dataSuites")
    public Object[] createTestSuites(int id, String TestSuite) {        
        return new Object[] {new clsTestCases(id, TestSuite)};        
    }

    @DataProvider(name="dataSuites")
    public static Object[][] dataProviderForTestSuites() {
        Object[][] dataArray = {{1, "Suite#1"},{2, "Suite#2"}};
        return dataArray;
    }
}

public class clsTestCases{  
    private int id;
    private String TestSuite;

    @Factory(dataProvider="dataCases")
    clsTestCases(int id, String TestSuite){
    this.id = id; 
    this.TestSuite = TestSuite;
    }    

    @DataProvider(name="dataCases")
    public static Object[][] dataProviderForTestCases() {
        Object[][] dataArray = {{1, "Case#1"},{2, "Case#2"}};
        return dataArray;
    }

    /*** i dont want to do this at present::: @Test (dataProvider="dataCases") ***/
    public void runTestCases(int id, String TestCase) {
        System.out.println("Executing Test Case "+ TestCase);
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the goal behind the use case but what you are trying to do is currently not possible (and I think it will never).

`@Factory` is a way to explain to TestNG how it should create an instance of the class (when on a constructor) or it let you the responsibility to create the instance yourself (when on a method).

If you create the instance yourself, you can't expect that TestNG will do extra things.

According to your sample, TestNG is supposed to have 4 instances of `clsTestCases`: "Suite#1", "Suite#2", "Case#1" and "Case#2".

Comment: So are you saying that it is NOT possible for Test Factory-1 to call another Test Factory-2. Any suggestions?